# Laravel 5.8 find com nome de coluna diferente de “id”, como fazer?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Bom Dia

No meu controler para fazer a view Show funcionar eu tenho seguinte código

```
public function show($id){
$produto = Produtos::find($id);
return view('produtos.produtosShow', array('produto' => $produto));}
```

Quando digito na url public/produtos/1, está funcionando corretamente.

Mas eu quero mudar a busca do **id** por outro campo como por exemplo o código do produto.

Minha tabela **Produtos** tem seguintes campos, *id, codigo, descrição.*

quero poder digitar na url *public/produtos/***códigoDoProduto** e visualizar o produto conforme o código digitado.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deverá então utilizar o método [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses).

Se a coluna código tem valores únicos ao invés de `$produto = Produtos::find($id)` use `$produto = Produtos::where('codigo', $codigo)->first()`

Vai ter que mudar na sua *view* para invés de passar o `id` passar o código como argumento.

Mude na função `show` o parâmetro para `$codigo`.

```
public function show($codigo)
{
    $produto = Produtos::where('codigo', $codigo)->first();
    return view('produtos.produtosShow', array('produto' => $produto));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e pela explicação

Answer (score 1):

O método find do Eloquent pesquisa pela chave primária. Se quiser pesquisar por outra coluna, use o método ->where()

```
public function show($cod)
{
    $produto = Produtos::where('codigo', $cod)->first();
    return view('produtos.produtosShow', ['produto' => $produto]);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda